# Is there any way given a column, which table it belongs using SQL Query?

Tags: database

Is there any way given a column, which table it belongs using SQL Query?

Comment: you mean, when you have the results of an SQL statement, know from which tables column are computed? I suppose that this is not possible, but maybe I am wrong, then what RDBMS are you using (for other people)?

Comment: Please clarify. "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, ... and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form." IMO. Notwithstanding the fact that 4 people have tried to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, Assuming this is SQL server db, you can check the below query -

```
select [name], object_name(id) from sys.columns where [name] like '%columnname%'
```

the object_name(id) will give you the table name for your columnname specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this using Sql Server 2005+

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(c.OBJECT_ID) TableName, c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c
WHERE c.name = '<column name>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id)
FROM    syscolumns
WHERE [name] = 'mycolumn'`

Comment: Use the `sys` catalog views in SQL Server 2005 and newer - `sys.columns` instead of `syscolumns`

Answer (score 0):

Using the syscolumns table (and assuming you just have the column name), you can figure out which tables contain a column with that name.  But beyond that you might be stuck.

Comment: Use the `sys` catalog views in SQL Server 2005 and newer - `sys.columns` instead of `syscolumns`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out which table a particular column in a query came from then the best bet is to alias all columns at the time you write queries. I would not accept any code in a code review that doesn't do this because it is a pain to figure out later.